Tests of entanglement between one and many qubits
I have a 5-qubit state $|\psi \rangle$, which has a physical interpretation that the middle qubit is the "impurity" with spin $s_{imp} = 1/2$. The rest 4 qubits highlight the presence of electrons with up or down spins in the two lead sites (the 4th and 5th qubits highlight the up spins, 1st and 2nd qubits highlight the down spins). With two electrons in the leads, the lead sites may have total spin $s = 1$. I wish to find the entanglement between this spin-1 and the impurity spin-1/2 system (essentially entanglement between the middle qubit and the rest 4 qubits). What kind of tests are there that I can implement in Qiskit? I know some tests, like the Controlled-SWAP test, but that seems to highlight entanglement in a state, and not between subsystems of the state. There was some work on entanglement between spin-1 and spin-1/2 states but the concurrence included the non-linear operations of reduced density matrices and finding trace of square of such matrices (which I understand can be done easily in Qiskit, but I wish to find a procedure/circuit that can be implemented on a real Quantum computer). Something very helpful would be generalized Bell tests, if anything like that exists.
